# No module found error when using file in same folder in VS Code

Tags: python, class, visual-studio-code, module

I am writing a Webscraping application in VS Code. Pytho version is 3.9.

My folder structure in VS Code

[BeautifulSoup - Scraping_Quotes - locator
BeautifulSoup -Scraping_Quotes - Parsers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7X06i.png)

The locator directory has a quote_locators.py which has a class called QuoteLocator.

When I try to import this class in my quote.py in Parsers directory as below code, I get the "No Module Named locator" error. Code is reproduced below.

```
from locator.quote_locators import QuoteLocators

class QuoteParser:
    """ 
    Given one of the specific Quote divs, find out the data about the quote
    """
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Quote> {self.content}, by {self.author}>'

    @property
    def content(self):
        locator = QuoteLocators.CONTENT
        return self.parent.select_one(locator).string

    @property
    def author(self):
        locator = QuoteLocators.AUTHOR
        return self.parent.select_one(locator).string

    @property
    def tags(self):
        locator = QuoteLocators.TAGS
        return self.parent.select_one(locator)
```

my launch.json file (if it is relevant) has :

```
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        }
    ]
```

The same code works flawlessly in Pycharm.

About to give up on VSCode, any help is appreciated !!!

I have tried multiple suggestions in StackOverflow, but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following code to the file '`quote.py`', and change

'`from locator.quote_locators import QuoteLocators`' to '`from quote_locators import QuoteLocators`'.

like this:

> ```
> from os.path import dirname, abspath, join
> import sys
>
> # Find code directory relative to our directory
> THIS_DIR = dirname(__file__)             # Returns the full path of the script.
> CODE_DIR = abspath(join(THIS_DIR, '..', 'locator'))     # Returns the absolute path.
> sys.path.append(CODE_DIR)            # Import the required path.
>
> from quote_locators import QuoteLocators
> ```

Python looks for modules from '`sys.path`', and We can add modules to it through '`append`',

When using the relative path search, python will search in the current working directory. If it cannot be found, it will report an error. Therefore, we can use the absolute path to facilitate its search.

In addition, pay attention to the spelling of the file name and class name, and check whether the file name is renamed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my `.env` file as well as `settings.json. After correcting these to point at the correct paths, the system is able to import modules from different folders.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you did here? I've been butting my head up against the same issue for days now and can't figure it out.